# Autowiring Spring Services on Construction of Object

Tags: multithreading, spring, autowired

Is there a way I can have Spring inject dependencies on construction of an object at runtime, rather than when parsing the Spring XML files or on package-scan?

I've got some objects that extend Thread and do file transfers. It be nice to have the services these Thread sublasses depend on autowired, so I don't have to pass them all in the constructor.

BONUS QUESTION!

Is there anything I need to do with these Thread subclasses once they've done their run() implementation has finished? Do they need 'killing' somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the Spring injection facilities as is.  You can inject a [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) and let your objects use that.  No Threads will be killed or harmed by your application: Spring will manage them all.

Comment: duffymo: The @async annotation sounds unbelievably helpful. So I could use my existing @Services (that get instantiated and autowired via package-scan), annotate the method I want done asynchronously, and the TaskExecutor thingy willm run it in a separate thread with all the members of my @Service still available? If so, that's ace!